# A challenging problem on disjoint cosets

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Motivated by my negative solutions (see [this paper published in Chinese Ann. Math. 13A(1992)](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/18s.pdf)) to two open problems on disjoint residue calsses posed by A. P. Huhn and L. Megyesi [Discrete Math. 41(1982)], in 2004 I formulated the following general conjecture on disjoint cosets of subgroups.

**Conjecture**. Let $G_1,\ldots,G_k\ (k>1)$ be subgroups of a group $G$ with all the indices $[G:G_i]$ $(i=1,\ldots,k)$ finite. If the left cosets $a_1G_1,\ldots,a_kG_k$ are pairwise disjoint for some $a_1,\ldots,a_k\in G$, then 
$$\gcd([G:G_i],[G:G_j])\ge k\quad\text{for some}\ 1\le i<j\le k.$$

This appeared as Conjecture 1.2 of [my paper in Internat. J. Math. 17(2006)](http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/82f.pdf). I noted that it holds when $k=2$ or $G$ is a $p$-group, see Remark 1.5 and Remark 2.2 of the 2006 paper.

In 2007 Kevin O'Bryant confirmed the conjecture for $k\le20$ when $G$ is the additive group $\mathbb Z$ of integers, see [this paper](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/a30int2005/a30int2005.pdf).

In 2008 Wan-Jie Zhu proved the conjecture for $k=3,4$ with $G$ a general group, see [arXiv:0807.2207](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2207). In 2010, Zhu Gong (another student of Nanjing University whose bachelor thesis was supervised by me) confirmed the conjecture for $k=5$ (again with $G$ a general group). Since 2010, there is no further progress on the conjecture.

QUESTION: Is the above conjecture true?

Actually, it suffices to consider the conjecture only for finite groups. If $a_1G_1,\ldots,a_kG_k$ are disjoint left cosets in a group $G$ with all the indices $[G:G_i]\ (1\le i\le k)$ finite, then $H=(G_1\cap\ldots\cap G_k)_G$
(the normal core of $G_1\cap\ldots\cap G_k$) is of fnite index in $G$ and 
$\bar a_1\bar G_1,\ldots,\bar a_k\bar G_k$ are disjoint cosets in the finite group $\bar G=G/H$, where $\bar a_i=a_iH$ and $\bar G_i=G_i/H$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$. Clearly, $[\bar G:\bar G_i]=[G:G_i]$ for every $i=1,\ldots,k$.

The question has puzzled me and my students for many years. I ever turned to some group-theorists for help, but got no further progress. I consider the conjecture quite challenging, and I'd like to offer 200 US dollars as the prize for the first complete solution.

Your helpful comments are welcome!

Comment: This seems to be a strengthening of the Herzog—Schönheim conjecture. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08301 and the references therein for relevant literature.